# how i extract data from json format in Flask

Tags: json, forms, flask

I need help i don't now how to extract data from json format i want to make a search input  in json and after i take the info from MYSQLdb i got this

```
{"result":[[21,"bogdan333","bogdan333",0,"","templates/UPLOAD_FOLDERp7.jpg","",1],[22,"Bogdan3333","Bogdan3333",0,"","profile_pic/p12.jpg","back_pic/p5.jpg",1]]}
```

i dont now how to make to extract just the names "Bogdan3333" 
My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getState3(value){
    $.post("/search_index?medic={{session['medic']}}&id={{id_general_user}}&connect=connect",{searching:value},function(data2){
        $(".solutii").html(data2);
    });
}
</script>
 <form id="custom-search-form" method="POST" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="">
                <div class="input-append span12">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query mac-style" onkeyup="getState3(this.value)"  ng-model="firstName" placeholder="Search">

                    <div class="finder-search"><p class="firstName"> {{ firstName }}</p></div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And here is flask part:

```
@app.route('/search_index',methods=['POST','GET'])
def search_index():
    if request.method=="POST":
        search=request.form['searching']
        sql_search="SELECT * FROM register WHERE medic=1 AND uname LIKE '%"+str(search)+"%' LIMIT 20"
        conn=con.execute(sql_search)
        print(conn)
        get=con.fetchall()
        print(get)
##        return redirect(url_for("index",medic=session['medic'],id=session['id'],connect='connect'))
        return jsonify(result=get)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extracting data from json you need to convert the string to an adequate data object. Use Pythons `json` module for this.

```
import json
data = json.loads(yourjsonstring)

# now access your data
res = data['result']
```